# Eclipseで実行構成を開くとエラーが出ます。

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipseでコマンドライン引数を取って実行しようと思い、実行構成を開いたところ

> ```
> org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.isModularConfiguration(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Z
> ```

というエラーが発生しました。

コマンドプロンプトでeclipseの実行ファイルがある階層まで行き、

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

と実行しても結果は同じでした。

どうすれば実行できますでしょうか。

追記
OSはWindows10，Javaのバージョンは8.0，Eclipseはoxygen 1.0です．この環境にして一度もうまくいっていない状況です．
Eclipseのログには何も残っていないです．

Comment: Eclipseのログ(`WORKSPACE_HOME/.metadata/.log`)に何か出力されていませんか?

Comment: 使用されている環境(OS, JVM, Eclipseのエディション/バージョン)はどのようなものでしょうか。
また、特定の操作を行って以来起動できなくなった、ということでしょうか。あるいは当該環境にセットアップを行って以来一度も起動に成功していない、ということでしょうか。
(ちなみに該当メソッドは[こちら](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.debug/blob/48639e026d77b44f33518af32aafbee44575ef50/org.eclipse.jdt.launching/launching/org/eclipse/jdt/launching/JavaRuntime.java#L1052-L1071)のようです。)

Comment: ログを見ればわかると思いますが、ログに何もないであれば、eclipseを起動する前に、%eclipse%/workspace/.metadata直下の.logファイルを削除して、eclipseを再起動してみてね